# JIRA: subscriptions pulling in irrelevant items

Tags: jira

I have a simple filter in my JIRA.  It works fine when i run it manually.  So, i went ahead and subscribed to the filter.  In cron, it has been set to run once every 4 hours.  When it runs in this automated cron mode, it is pulling in some additional irrelevant items in the results.  What could be done to fix this please?

**My JQL:**

```
project =  “Migration for Customer" AND status in 
("READY FOR TEST", "Ready For QA", "In Test", "In QA", "In Development", "Ready to Test") 
AND status not in ("READ FOR SHOWCASE", "Ready for Release", "READY FOR RELEASE") 
ORDER BY status DESC
```

Result when ran manually: 32 records (as expected). 
Result when ran in cron mode: 41 records (the extra 9 records were marked "Ready for Release" long back but is shown as "In Development" in the report).

Comment: Hey, can you please share your JQL Filter in order to understand your problem better? If you are using custom fields, please also mention its data type.

Comment: hi @stuck: I have updated my question with JQL now.  thanks for checking this out.

Comment: First, I would try to reindex all issues in that _Mirgration for Customer_ project. In Jira Server/DC, go to project settings -> Re-index project.

Comment: hi @CraZ: Thank you.  I don't have this access but will try to reach our JIRA admin.  It might take a while though.  I will post the updates afterwards.